# Add signs to string according to another string

Tags: python, string, indexing

I have two strings:

```
protein = 'IHASEQSDCEKMNALLEKINAIYATDKAKAENYLAEARALKCDKYQEALNNFATIIIKDNSDKEE---LALSDCDVNKLQQLLSDKRLTPEKKIEYNA-LYSNINQANQ--ILNQDVA'
protein_structure = 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEECCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEETTTCHHHHHHHHHHCTCTCCCCEEEEEECCC'
```

I need to append `'-'` to `protein_structure`

```
aligned_structure_to_protein = 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEECCCCHHH---HHHHHHHHHHHHHEEETTTCHHHHHHHHHH-CTCTCCCCEE--EEEECCC'
```

I thought about finding index in protein string indexes of `'-'`, make list of `protein_structure` string and insert `'-'` by index. to list. And finally change list to string.

```
protein = 'IHASEQSDCEKMNALLEKINAIYATDKAKAENYLAEARALKCDKYQEALNNFATIIIKDNSDKEE---LALSDCDVNKLQQLLSDKRLTPEKKIEYNA-LYSNINQANQ--ILNQDVA'
protein_structure = 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEECCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEETTTCHHHHHHHHHHCTCTCCCCEEEEEECCC'

indexes_of_minus = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(protein) if ltr == '-']

list_of_structure_elements = list(protein_stucture)
```

But i dont know how to properly insert signs `'-'` into list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this after finding `indexes_of_minus`:

```
for i in indexes_of_minus:
    list_of_structure_elements.insert(i, '-')
```

then:

```
final = ''.join(list_of_structure_elements)
```

Test:

```
In [38]: final
Out[38]: 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEECCCCHHH---HHHHHHHHHHHHHEEETTTCHHHHHHHHHH-CTCTCCCCEE--EEEECCC'
```

Comment: not work propely final = 'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEECCCCHHH-H-H-HHHHHHHHHHHEEETTTCHHHHHHHHHHCTC-TCCCCEEEEEE-C-CCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHTHHEEHHHTTCCCCHHHHHHHHEECCTTTTTTTCTEEEEEEHCCHHHHHHHHHHHHH-H-H-H-H-HHHHHHHETTTTTTTEEEECCCCHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHT-TTTCCTTEEEEEEEEEEHHHHEEEETCCCTTT'

Comment: @MTG I have edited, check now. that `n` was redundant.